# After applying apply(), I got a "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [5, 6, 7]})
df.apply(lambda x: 'good' if x >= 2  else 'bad')
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

You're applying to the whole dataframe, so `x >= 2` is column wise, which gives a `Series` of multiple `True`s and `False`s, so try `applymap`:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: 'good' if x >= 2  else 'bad')
```

Or even better use `np.where`:

```
>>> df[:] = np.where(df >= 2, 'good', 'bad')
>>> df
      A     B
0   bad  good
1  good  good
2  good  good
>>>
```